# cause + noun + to infinitive

Tags: meaning, grammar, adjectives, adverbs, infinitives

> Once you’re on your journey, certain wheels cause friction to control
> movement toward either side of the track, resulting in a loss of
> energy.

Does "to control" specify the verb "cause" or the objective "friction"?

I'm not sure whether the sentence has the meaning of "wheels cause friction, and then, as a result of it, wheels control movement." or the meaning of " wheels cause friction which controls movement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does "to control" specify the verb "cause" or the objective
> "friction"?

Neither.

This is an adjunct of purpose, adjuncts being modifiers in clause structure. It answers the question ***why*** *certain wheels cause friction onc*e...

> ...certain wheels cause friction [**in order** to control movement
> toward either side of the track]...

Whenever it's possible to insert *in order* in front of *to* without changing the meaning, it's an adjunct of purpose.

Result adjuncts typically take the form of gerund-participial clauses (-*ing* clauses) such as the *resulting...* one in the example given. They can also start with *so* or *with the result*. Note neither one of these may be substituted while maintaining the meaning of the original.

> ...certain wheels cause friction [**with the result** that they control movement
> toward either side of the track]...
>
> ...certain wheels cause friction [**so** they control movement
> toward either side of the track]...

Comment: What's the difference between the given sentence above and "The flood causes the river to overflow"? I think the second sentence is like using causative structure, in which "to overflow' is used as an objective complement.... I guess... Is it possible to apply causative structure to interpret or understand the first sentence?

Comment: @HanJeBae No. In your second example it's not possible to insert _**in order**_ before _to overflow_, and we don't understand _to overflow_ as answering _**why**_ _the flood causes the river_. That's two clear signs of the difference between the two.